# Efficient shortest path in DAG with Python's graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

**Task:** I want to compute a shortest path between a source and target node in a DAG (directed acyclic graph) using Python's `graph-tool` **efficiently**. My DAG has negative weights.

In theory, this is a computationally "easy" problem (i.e., *O(V + E)*) by first computing a topological sorting of the graph and then visiting and updating parent nodes and distances (e.g. as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482619/shortest-path-for-a-dag)).

How can I implement this efficiently using `graph-tool`?

My failed attempts so far:

- manually implementing the theoretically efficient algorithm in Python. Since I have to loop over each vertex in the graph, however, this becomes unacceptably slow
- using `shortest_path` function from `graph-tool` to call the Dijkstra routine from `Boost Graph Library` would have an acceptable running time, but doesn't fully exploit the DAG structure and doesn't work for negative weights anyways
- using `shortest_path`  to call `Bellman-Ford` returns a correct shortest path, but doesn't exploit the DAG structure and is too slow (*O(VE)*).

The efficient DAG shortest path algorithm is implemented as `dag_shortest_paths` in the underlying [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/dag_shortest_paths.html). Is there any way of accessing this function through `graph-tool` or any other way of computing this efficiently with `graph-tool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality has been added to the git version of graph-tool:

https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/commit/012787ecde818efc2b893ad0d8aff819b8deb6ca

An optional parameter `dag=True` can now  be passed to `shortest_path()` that achieves what you want.

Comment: Thank you! :) Could you please clarify on the behaviour of the negative_weights flag if `dag=True` is passed? On a trial run, a call to `shortest_path` with `dag=True, negative_weights=False` runs considerably faster than with `dag=True, negative_weights=True` even though for DAGs, negative weights should not affect the running time

Comment: The `negative_weights=True` parameter triggers the Bellman-Ford algorithm. When using `dag=True`, there is no need to pass `negative_weights=True`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use the Networkx library? Since I know, it's efficient, works for weighted and non-weighted graphs, and it's very simple to use.

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path

An example:

```
    >>> import networkx as nx

    >>> G=nx.path_graph(5)
    >>> path=nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G)
    >>> print(path[0][4])

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thank you for your answer, but I'm explicitly looking for a solution that uses `graph-tool` and that can be used with netagive edge weights. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to exploit the DAG structure.